# When to instantiate the repository and which is the lifespan of it?

Tags: repository, domain-driven-design

In DDD, is the application layer who uses the repository to get the data from database, call the methods of the domain and then call the repository to persists the data. Something like that:

```
public void MyApplicationService()
{
    Order myOrder = _orderRepository.Get(1);
    myOrder.Update(data);
    _orderRepository.Commit();
}
```

In this example the repository is a class variable that it is instantiate in the constructor of the service, so its life is the life of the class.

But I am wondering if it wouldn't be better to instantiate a repository for each action that I want to do, to have a shorter life, because if not, if I use the class for many actions, the repository will have many entities that perhaps it will not need more.

So I was thinking in a solution like this:

```
public void MyApplicationService()
{
    OrderRepository myOrderRepository = new OrderRepository(_options);
    Order myOrder = myOrderRepository.GetOrder(1);
    myOrder.Update(data);
    myOrderRepository.Commit();
    myOrderRepository.Dispose();
}
```

So a new instance each time I need to do the action.

So in sumary, I would like to know about the differents solutions and the advantages and disadvanges to decide the lifespan of the repository.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended lifespan of the repository is *one business transaction*.

Your second patch of code is correct in that aspect, however it has one drawback: you have created a strong dependency between the `ApplicationService` and `OrderRepository` classes. With your code, you are not able to isolate both class in order to unit test them separately. Also, you need to update the `ApplicationService` class whenever you change the constructor of the `OrderRepository`. If `OrderRepository` requires parameters to construct, then you have to construct them (which implies to reference their type and base types), despite this being an implementation detail of `OrderRepository` (needed for data persistence store access) and not needed for your application service layer.

For these reasons, most of modern program development rely on a pattern called [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI). With DI, you specify that your `ApplicationService` class depends on an instance of the `OrderRepository` class, or better, an interface `IOrderRepository` whom the `OrderRepository` class implements. The dependency is declared by adding a parameter in the `ApplicationService` constructor:

```cs
public interface IOrderRepository : IDisposable
{
  Order GetOrder(int id);
  void Commit();
}
```

```cs
public class ApplicationService
{
  private readonly OrderRepository orderRepository;

  public ApplicationService(IOrderRepository orderRepository)
  {
    this.orderRepository = orderRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(orderRepository));
  }

  public void Update(int id, string data)
  {
    Order myOrder = orderRepository.Get(id);
    myOrder.Update(data);
    orderRepository.Commit();
  }
}
```

Now the DI library is responsible to construct `OrderRepository` and inject the instance in the `ApplicationService` class. If `OrderRepository` has its own dependencies, the library will resolve them first and construct the whole object graph so you don't have to do that yourself. You simply need to tell your DI library what specific implementation you want for each referenced interface. For example in C#:

```cs
public IServiceCollection AddServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  return services.AddScoped<IOrderRepository,OrderRepository>();
}
```

When unit testing your code, you can replace the actual implementation of `OrderRepository` with a mock object, such as `Mock<IOrderRepository>` or your own `MockOrderRepository` implementation. The code under test is then *exactly* the code in production, all wiring being done by the DI framework.

Most modern DI libraries have support for object lifetime management, including transient (always resolve a new object), singleton (always reuse the same object), or scoped (each scope has a single instance). The latter is what is used to isolate objects instance per business transaction, using a singleton `ScopeFactory` to create scopes whenever you start a business transaction:

```cs
public class UpdateOrderUseCase : UseCase
{
  private readonly IScopeFactory scopeFactory;

  public UpdateOrderUseCase(IScopeFactory scopeFactory) // redacted

  public void UpdateOrder(int id, string data)
  {
    using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
    var orderRepository = scope.GetService<IOrderRepository>();
    var order = orderRepository.Get(id);
    order.Update(data);
    orderRepository.Commit();
    // disposing the scope will also dispose the object graph
  }
}
```

When you implement a REST service, that transaction usually corresponds to one HTTP request. Modern frameworks, such as asp.net core, will automatically create scopes per HTTP request and use that to resolve your dependency graph later in the framework internals. This means you don't even have to handle the ScopeFactory yourself.